# How to hide XML Configuration File

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

I have just finished making my application and finished building it. And everything is working fine.

And then I notice an XML Configuration file in the folder, So I click it.

And there it is, my whole connectionstrings along with my remote sql server ip address, login username and login password which is visible for all to see.

I tried deleting the XML Configuration file and ran the program, it just makes a App_Data folder inside the folder with a default database.

Is there any way to hide the XML Configuration file or make it unreadable, as it contains all my connection info.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you embed the xml config file [as a resource](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292)? It still won't be safe from a determined hacker but it's better than having the file in plain sight. I doubt there's any 100% effective way to store this information in a client assembly; you'd be better off connecting to a service, but that is a big design change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this MS article regarding securing your connection strings:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/protecting-connection-information

Alternatively, hard-code the connection string into your application (note:  malicious users can reverse engineer .net apps fairly easily), or use Integrated Security if possible.

Comment: Retired documentation

Answer (score 1):

You can either encrypt it: http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/08/11/how-to-encrypt-connection-string-in-webconfig/

or use Integrated Security if you can.

Comment: -1 this isn't really a workable solution. The key will be on the user's computer (if it isn't good luck decrypting it) The user account will also have to have access to the key in order for the application to use it. If the user has access to it... you've implemented security through obfuscation.

Comment: I don't think this wpf app is using asp.net (based on the tag)

Comment: That link is for ASP.NET- the tag for the question is WPF, although you can trick it to work. Alternatively it can be done in code- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.protectsection.aspx

Comment: @RichardOD you still have a pretty severe key management issue.

Comment: @Conrad - of course if it's on the user's machine a determined user can get the value, it sounds like all the OP wanted was obfuscation

Comment: @Conrad- I agree. I wasn't recommending this approach. Personally I believe encryption only usually makes sense for servers.

Answer (score 1):

Any attempts to hide the connection string will just make it slightly more difficult to access for both you and any attackers.  It is not unusual but not very secure and there is also the problem with ensuring regular password rotation.

If you can, switch to integrated security.  (Include `Integrated Security=SSPI` in the connection string, but no user name or password.)  The connection will be created using your own user account (or the account running your code), assuming that

- You are using MS SQL Server
- The SQL Server is on the same system, or in the same AD domain and will be thus able to recognize the account.

Comment: Also assumes that SQL Server is the target Database.

Comment: That's true.  I'll edit to make this clear.  The question only mentions .NET and no setup circumstances.

Comment: Hi, Yes the target database on my remote server is SQL Server. But if they use this kind of connections, with no username or login password, how will they be able to connect to the database? As they did not specify any login credentials to get access to it

Comment: @MarkMackanga - Your code executes under a user account.  You can add SQL Server roles to this account using `sp_addrolemember`, and after that it will be able to connect.  In case of SQL Server 2005 (or anything upgraded from it) the `Administrators` group will have enough rights by default so you can start experimenting with that before defining the production rights.

Comment: Oh alright, I get it now. And yeah Thats exactly What I did. Thanks for the reply and swift response!

Answer (score 1):

A dedicated debugger will be able to see your connection string pretty much no matter what you do.

Remember if you can look at `Connection.ConnectionString` in a debug session so can a user with WinDBG or Visual Studio. So even if you encrypt the file the user can just let you decrypt and then inspect the clear text value.

This is why many client applications (especially mobile ones) that need information from a server typically don't directly connect to a database. Instead they typically connect to a service instead. Then you authorize and authenticate the user against your service.